# Eclipse 2018-12 : Adding Tomcat Runtime Environment

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, runtime

Upgraded to Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0) and I'm trying to add Tomcat as a server runtime environment but it's no longer an option. How do I add it back?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't install the **JST Server Adapter Extensions** feature.

Also, 2019-03 came out a couple of days ago. It makes this a little clearer since you should now be able to search the 2019-03 update site for "tomcat" and get a match.